# Excel Sumif with number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=SUMIF(A1:A14, "102000*", B1:B14)

Why it cannot filter the value starts with 10200?

[image]

Comment: The reason probably is that the values in column A aren't strings but numbers. If so, the value you are looking for isn't "10200*". Instead it should be ">"&1020000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Suppose you want to add numbers like `1020001`, then enter it as criteria in cell `D74`, and use this formula.

  `{=SUM((B74:B82)*(--(A74:A82=D74)))}`
- If you have more criteria, like I've shown in `D74` & in `E74`, then use this one in `C74`.

  ```
  {=SUM((B74:B82)*(--(A74:A82=D74)+(--(A74:A82=E74))))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Glad to help you  @Bryant Tang ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a new column using the formula

```
left(a1,5)
```

Then base the sumif off that new column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of occurences, you can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(--LEFT(A1:A7,5)=10200))
```

and if you actually want to sum values, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(--LEFT(A1:A7,5)=10200)*(B1:B7))
```

[image]